How to make a slanting line as a border on a section on which clip-path is applied in reactjs tailwindCSS
I wanted to create a slanting line in a section.On that section I wanted a border / line which should be a linear gradient.Or such that the line should be cut in some interval and then continue.I am attaching the image of the design as I wanted.
Now let me explain my strategy.I am using a section and on that section tag I have applied clip-path.But that clip-path has only gave me a slanting line which is 100% responsive across multiple devices.Now the issue of the orange breaking line.How should I strategize in order to solve this problem.
My code.


.section-two{
  clip-path: polygon(100% 15%, 0 0%, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
  position: relative;  
  z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1A2227;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem; /* This is the equivalent of pb-10 in Tailwind (10 * 0.25rem) */
    height: auto;
  
}
 <section className="section-two flex flex-col bg-[#1A2227] md:h-[85vh] h-max pb-10">
</section>



I am attaching the design I wanted.

This is what I have done so far but still it is not working.
